# What is this component? It locks magnet when powered

Tags: magnetics, gear

these 2 discs are part of a vehicle gear level control. Operation is, you push button on the gear level and then you can change vehicle gear position (eg 1, 2, neutral, reverse etc)

Photo show side views of this mechanism. When button is not pushed, these 2 discs are touching each other. When button is pushed, they come apart (open position) and gear position can be changed.

[image: drawing]

Between the 2 wires, resistance is a constant 266-270 ohms. when current is flowing (there's no polarity), the 2 discs can't be pulled apart. So this forms a locking mechanism for the gear level.

Question: what is this component connected to the 2 wires???

Comment: drawing link- https://imgur.com/a/uNRipwJ

Comment: Sorry but that is not much to go on. A simple guess is that it is a electromagnet.

Comment: It is called an electromagnetic clutch

Comment: i believe you're correct. the item looks very similar to items here: https://au.rs-online.com/web/c/pneumatics-hydraulics-power-transmission/power-transmission-clutches-brakes/clutches-electromagnetic/